# Тип не помечен как сериализуемый

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно создать компонент для нужд проекта. Вот максимально упрощённый код:

```
[Serializable()]
public partial class TabControl2 : TabControl
{
    private List<TabPage> userPages;
    public Dictionary<int, DrawItemEventArgs> AllItemsDraw { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, DrawItemEventArgs>();

    public TabControl2():base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public TabControl2(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Add(this);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void InitializeComponent()
    {
        DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        userPages = new List<TabPage>();

        userPages.Add(new TabPage() { Text = "test1", BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None, BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark });
        Controls.Add(userPages.ElementAt(0));
        userPages.Add(new TabPage() { Text = "test2", BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None, BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark });
        Controls.Add(userPages.ElementAt(1));
        userPages.Add(new TabPage() { Text = "test_full_please", BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None, BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark });
        Controls.Add(userPages.ElementAt(2));

    }
// etc...
}
```

При взаимодействии с новым компонентом в конструкторе форм появляется следующая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем ошибаюсь? Благодарю.

Comment: вероятно тип `DrawItemEventArgs` не помечен как сериализуемый

Comment: @tym32167 как я написал - делаю новый компонент. Это нарушит его создание, дальше будет выдаваться еще более странные ошибки.

Comment: А серализация компонента формы разве работает? Вроде, компонент при создании всякие хендлы создает => если его восстановить на другой машине, то хендлы будут не рабочими.

Comment: @iluxa1810 пробовал, но вываливалась следующая ошибка.в течении 24 часов покажу её, если интересно. Её я вообще не знал как лечить Но она чисто из-за сериализации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение:
При создании пользовательского контрола студия пытается создать объекты всех свойств контрола, для отображения их в дизайнере. Это и блокирует форму и вызывает вышеописанную ошибку. Решение:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

Пометить атрибутом нужные свойства.

Comment: Вроде наоборот было, атрибут вешался на то, что нужно пробросить в дизайнер... это в какой версии студии?

Comment: @rdorn 17я. Только это решение заставило дизайнер адекватно отображаться.